# How do I use 32-bit signed integer's complement to represent an integer in javascript

Tags: javascript

example:
I'm going to use `0xC0000000` (32-bit signed complement)  for `-2^30`

```js
const num = Number('0xC0000000')
console.log(num === -Math.pow(2,30)) // expected: true
```

Comment: That's 2^27 + 2^26, that is not -2^30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript only has two's complement integers in two places:

1. As a temporary value during some operations. The bitwise operators use 32-bit ints, and some `Math` object methods work with 32-bit int values (for example, [`imul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul)).
2. As an element in a `Int16Array`, `Int32Array`, or `Int64Array`. (`Int32Array` in your case.)

Otherwise, all numbers are either `number` (IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point) or `BigInt` (arbitrary-precision non-two's-complement integers).

So for instance, you can have a two's complement in a single-element `Int32Array`.

```js
const array = Int32Array.from([0xC000000]);
console.log(array[0].toString(16));
```

However, whenever you *use* that 32-bit integer, it gets converted to `number`. That said, JavaScript's conversions between `number` and 32-bit signed int are fairly smart. For example, consider this two's complement boundary condition:

```js
const array = Int32Array.from([0x7FFFFFFF]);
console.log(array[0].toString(16)); // 7fffffff
++array[0];
console.log(array[0].toString(16)); // -80000000
```

That's what you'd want for a two's complement operation, even though it isn't a two's complement operation (in theory; JavaScript engines are allowed to optimize). The operation is 32-bit two's complement int to `number`, increment `number`, convert `number` back to 32-bit two's complement int. But we still get the desired result.

Comment: the answer is `Math.imul()` (The function returns the result of the C-like 32-bit multiplication of the two parameters)